# htaccess clean url redirecting to folder if it has the same name

Tags: .htaccess

I used this script I found here:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\w+\ /(.*)\.php(\?.*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .* $0.php
```

But I have a page, web.php, which redirects to /web
However, because I also have (an unrelated) folder /web/  that page /web(.php) in my main directory gets redirected to /web/(index.php)

Is there any way to prevent this? I was thinking like If /web/index.php doesnt exist, just show /web(.php) else show /web/(index.php)  or anything that will accomplish this.